# How to solve the calendar task issue in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

Here, I settings the therapist working time using schedule wise and additional time schedule wise.
The therapist **nancy fernadez** time schedule is :

1. Extra(additional) working time for her the date 31-05-2017 is 10:00:00 to 14:00:00 i.e in 12 hours is 10:00 am to 2:00 pm
2. schedule working time for her the date 31-05-2017 is 14:00:00 to 19:00:00 i.e in 12 hours is 2:00 pm to 7:00 pm

   **Nancy fernadez** is available in whole day i.e. 10:00 am to 7:00 pm.

   **Question :**
   I book my booking time between 13:25 to 14:25 i.e. 01:25 pm to 02:25 pm. It will give me error like therapist not available at that time... actually as per schedule **nancy** is available for this time...

**here is image of task assign calendar**

[image]

**Here, is below my mysql query for Additional working time for her**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM `extra_day`
INNER JOIN `therapist` ON `thrp_id` = `exd_thrp_id`
WHERE `exd_thrp_id` = '3'
AND `exd_date` = '2017-05-31'
AND `exd_from` <= '13:25:00'
AND `exd_to` >= '14:25:00'
```

**Here, is below my mysql query for schedule wise working time for her**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.*, CONCAT(th.thrp_fname, " ", th.thrp_surname) AS thrp_name
FROM `schedule` `s`
INNER JOIN `therapist` `th` ON `s`.`schd_thrp_id` = `th`.`thrp_id`
WHERE `schd_thrp_id` = '3'
AND `schd_day` = '3'
AND `schd_from` <= '13:25:00'
```

**I check the availability of therapist using below controller**

```
// check if therapist comes on this day (regular schedule or extra day) 
            $this->load->model('schedule_model');
            $schedule = $this->schedule_model->Get(NULL, array('schd_thrp_id' => $data['bk_thrp_id'],
                'schd_day' => date('N', strtotime($data['bk_start'])),
                'schd_from' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_start']))
            ));

            $this->load->model('additional_work_model');
            $additional_work = $this->additional_work_model->Get(NULL, array('exd_thrp_id' => $data['bk_thrp_id'],
                'exd_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['bk_start'])),
                'exd_from' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_start'])),
                'exd_to' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_end']))
            ));
            if ($schedule['countFiltered'] == 0 && $additional_work['countFiltered'] == 0) {
                $response['status'] = 'failure';
                $response['errormsg'] = 'Therapist not available.';
                return $response;
            }
```

Please ask me, If any query related to question

Thanks for your help...

Comment: still you didn't find Solution?

Comment: @Nawin, Nope I didn't found

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query. Because `extra_day` `exd_from` condition work but `exd_to` condition will not work because the to time is `14:00:00` only. And the Second query will not get because start time is `14:00:00` but you get `13:25:00`. You need to join the two tables to get the result. or you need to give some conditions like if the staff is working `extra_day` row count

**UPDATE**

I Change your query with my assumption you can Change it like and join query also you can change what table you want:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, exd_date, exd_from, exd_to
FROM `extra_day`
INNER JOIN `therapist` ON `thrp_id` = `exd_thrp_id`
WHERE `exd_thrp_id` = '3'
AND `exd_date` = '2017-05-31'
AND `exd_from` <= '13:25:00'
AND `exd_to` >= '14:25:00'

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.*, CONCAT(th.thrp_fname, " ", th.thrp_surname) AS thrp_name, schd_from
FROM `schedule` `s`
INNER JOIN `therapist` `th` ON `s`.`schd_thrp_id` = `th`.`thrp_id`
WHERE `schd_thrp_id` = '3'
AND `schd_day` = '3'
AND `schd_from` <= '13:25:00'

$this->load->model('schedule_model');
$schedule = $this->schedule_model->Get(NULL, array('schd_thrp_id' => $data['bk_thrp_id'],
    'schd_day' => date('N', strtotime($data['bk_start'])),
    'schd_from' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_start']))
));

$this->load->model('additional_work_model');
$additional_work = $this->additional_work_model->Get(NULL, array('exd_thrp_id' => $data['bk_thrp_id'],
    'exd_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['bk_start'])),
    'exd_from' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_start'])),
    'schd_to' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_end']))
));
if($additional_work['exd_from'] <= date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_start'])) && $schedule['schd_from'] >= date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_start']))){
    $get_now_with_anymodel = $this->your_model->Get(NULL, array('exd_thrp_id' => $data['bk_thrp_id'],
    'exd_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['bk_start'])),
    'exd_from' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_start'])),
    'exd_to' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($data['bk_end']))
    /*
    Your Model query:
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, exd_date, exd_from, exd_to
    FROM `extra_day` AS A
    INNER JOIN `therapist` AS B ON B.`thrp_id` = A.`exd_thrp_id`
    INNER JOIN `schedule` AS C ON C.`schd_thrp_id` = A.`exd_thrp_id`
    WHERE `exd_thrp_id` = '3'
    AND `exd_date` = '2017-05-31'
    AND A.`exd_from` <= '13:25:00'
    AND C.`schd_to` >= '14:25:00'
    */
));
}
```

$additional_work['exd_from'] is your return result from your model Change it like how you return the data

Comment: Yes , I Know. But how I can change in query. I change the query for this particular issue then its may be affecting to another booking.

Comment: I can't join two table because , additional work and extra work their are two different model in my structure. If I combine two table, for that I have to create new model that is not valid. If I join two table in additional booking model then its harm to another booking..

Comment: You have `schd_to` field?

Comment: Yes, I have this field

Comment: Okay, @Nawin Thank you

Comment: have you create new model for both the table ?

Comment: No, I just add that table you can use that any of your  both modal with other function name and you can call that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150055/discussion-between-angel-and-nawin).